# Decimal object converting to scientific notation in Python

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal, string-formatting, precision

I've read through the Decimal documentation and researched other methods around suppressing scientific notation expression in Python, but I am having an issue with the Decimal package not working as I expect, and I cannot figure out how to get my desired output.

I have a string - `my_tick = "0.0000005"`

```
type(my_tick)
<class 'str'>
```

When I pass this into Decimal(), the object is formatted and returned in scientific notation:

```
from decimal import *

formatted_tick = Decimal(my_tick)
print(formatted_tick)
5E-7
```

If I call `getcontext()` I see that my default precision is set to 28 decimal places:

```
getcontext()
Context(prec=28, rounding=ROUND_HALF_EVEN, Emin=-999999, Emax=999999, capitals=1, clamp=0, flags=[InvalidOperation, FloatOperation], traps=[InvalidOperation, DivisionByZero, Overflow])
```

I have tried to wrap the string as a float, but it still returns in scientific notation:

```
formatted_tick = Decimal(repr(float(my_tick)))
print(formatted_tick)
5E-7
```

Both result in a Decimal object with a value of 5E-7

For my function, it must remain a decimal object with a value of `0.0000005`, as far as formatting, I may have this same issue with other numbers, and I do not necessarily know the precision ahead of time so a native solution that can  handle precision of 1 to 10 decimal places on it's own is needed. Does anyone know why Decimal is using scientific notation when the precision is set to 28?

Thank you ahead of time,

Comment: You need to be careful to distinguish between `Decimal` objects and string representations of those objects. A `Decimal` object isn't related to any particular representation: `Decimal("1e-7")` and `Decimal("0.0000001")` give the exact same object. In this question, you're asking for a specific *representation* of your `Decimal` object, and that's the domain of string formatting, as in @MatthewStory's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [str.format](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#format) will format your number the way you want if you specify that it should be outputted as a `float` with `:f` like this:

```
>>> "{:f}".format(decimal.Decimal("0.0000000005"))
"0.0000000005"
```

If you wanted this behavior to be the default string representation behavior for your decimal you could define a class like this:

```
 class NoScientificNotation(decimal.Decimal):
     def __str__(self):
         return "{:f}".format(self)
```

And then use it like a `Decimal:

```
>>> NoScientificNotation("0.0000000005")
Decimal('0.0000000005')
```

Without issue.

Comment: Interesting, can I ask what version of python and Decimal you are using? I suspect something else is going on with my program. If I run your code, I still receive the output in scientific notation.

Comment: I have verified this in both 2.7 and 3.5, in both cases the decimal prints in scientific notation unless i format to a float, which causes it to print as expected.

Comment: I think the issue is that .format is not working as I expect, if I run your first line - type("{:f}".format(decimal.Decimal("0.0000000005"))) I get <class 'str'> as the output when it should be a float. Im using python 3.6 and I have never overriden any formatting settings. I will have to dig deeper, thank you for your contribution.

Comment: The `type` of `"{:f}".format(...)` will always be a string ... as you are converting it explicitly to a string. `notation` is only ever important when converting a `Decimal` to a string as the internal decimal representation is always the same. What my 2 suggested fixes do is to make sure that when you display that `Decimal` it is always displayed the way you want.